# UTF-8 and ÅÄÖ special characters PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

Hi have a look at this picture: http://ctrlv.in/175196 and as you can see the ÅÄÖ are replaced with �.

I have this at the very top of my php: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>`

and when I look at source it is indeed utf-8 - so why dont they display properly?

Comment: your file is not save as utf-8

Comment: What makes you think your file is UTF-8? Using characters `äåö` and writing `"this file is utf-8"` (the meta tag is like that) does not make a file UTF-8.

Comment: http://ctrlv.in/175198 I thought I cleared that by having these settings? Is it something with the normalization form?

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson where is the text coming from? From the database? You need to `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` before making any queries. If the text is literally written to the file, then it should just work.

Comment: Well no it didnt. Yes I am, I am a beginner, what should I use instead? The text is coming from a token which is sent after a user makes a purchase and then are redirectedt to this pdt.php. The token tx holds data about the products bought and the user that bught them. And I dont use a DB atm.

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson Ok but where is the token coming from? Where is the customer name data written in if not in a database? I guess you could google for PHP IDEs (Integrated Development Environments), I don't have particular recommendations but they should work much better for PHP than a HTML editor

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. The token is coming from PayPal and I manipulate that string and takes out for example first_name, last_name and so on. That is just displayed as a receipt and a mail is also sent with the same details. I guess I need to learn how to resave a file to utf-8

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson wait, how are you manipulating it? Standard PHP string functions can screw up UTF-8 encoded strings, for example substr. Have you also verified that Paypal sends it to you in UTF-8?

Comment: Im just saving them to $vars and echoing them. I tried notepad++ and utf-8 without BOM and save it and upload but no change.

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson that doesn't change the encoding of the customer name because as you said, the customer name comes from Paypal - not from your file. The file encoding only affects strings that are directly in your file. It doesn't affect strings coming from database, 3rd party services etc.

Comment: And therefore I cant do aything about it except send PayPal a mail and a question about it? Since the vars probably already are "corrupted" when I get them.

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson read the Paypal API documentation you are using, they probably have documented how to change the charset with a parameter or similar

Answer (score 4):

When you see the UNICODE REPLACEMENT CHARACTER �, it means your text is being interpreted as UTF-8 (or another *Unicode encoding*), but one of the byte sequences in the file was not valid in this encoding.

In other words, the file is ***not*** UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: http://ctrlv.in/175198 I thought I cleared that by having these settings? Is it something with the normalization form? Should I try to set that to none?

Comment: No, you just need to actually save the file as UTF-8 in your text editor. I have no idea how to do that in Dreamweaver, consult the help or use a real editor. ;-P Maybe read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more help/info.

Comment: Well I tried to donwoad Notepad++ but in it the encoding already are utf-8 without bom. Tried to change to another encoding and then back and upload. No change.

Comment: If the data is indeed not coming from the file itself but is inserted via code, as the comments to the question reveal, then it depends on how exactly you handle the data coming from Paypal. Can't help there without more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $your_variable);
```

if that is coming from an sql query `set_charset('utf8')` first before the query.

Answer (score 0):

using notepad++ try encoding utf-8 without bom

Comment: I am trying that atm, but with no change.